# Getting predicted values at response scale using broom::augment function

Tags: r, statistics, glm, predict, broom

I'm fitting `glm` model in `R` and can get predicted values at response scale using `predict.glm(object=fm1, type="response")` where `fm1` is the fitted model. I wonder how to get predicted values at response scale using `augment` function from `broom` package. My minimum working example is given below.

```
Dilution <- c(1/128, 1/64, 1/32, 1/16, 1/8, 1/4, 1/2, 1, 2, 4)
NoofPlates <- rep(x=5, times=10)
NoPositive <- c(0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5)
Data <- data.frame(Dilution,  NoofPlates, NoPositive)


fm1 <- glm(formula=NoPositive/NoofPlates~log(Dilution),
           family=binomial("logit"), data=Data, weights=NoofPlates)
predict.glm(object=fm1, type="response")
# 1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9         10 
# 0.02415120 0.07081045 0.19005716 0.41946465 0.68990944 0.87262421 0.95474066 0.98483820 0.99502511 0.99837891 

library(broom)
broom::augment(x=fm1)

# NoPositive.NoofPlates log.Dilution. X.weights.    .fitted   .se.fit     .resid       .hat    .sigma
# 1                    0.0    -4.8520303          5 -3.6989736 1.1629494 -0.4944454 0.15937234 0.6483053
# 2                    0.0    -4.1588831          5 -2.5743062 0.8837030 -0.8569861 0.25691194 0.5662637
# 3                    0.4    -3.4657359          5 -1.4496388 0.6404560  1.0845988 0.31570923 0.4650405
# 4                    0.4    -2.7725887          5 -0.3249714 0.4901128 -0.0884021 0.29247321 0.6784308
# 5                    0.6    -2.0794415          5  0.7996960 0.5205868 -0.4249900 0.28989252 0.6523116
# 6                    0.8    -1.3862944          5  1.9243633 0.7089318 -0.4551979 0.27931425 0.6486704
# 7                    1.0    -0.6931472          5  3.0490307 0.9669186  0.6805552 0.20199632 0.6155754
# 8                    1.0     0.0000000          5  4.1736981 1.2522190  0.3908698 0.11707018 0.6611557
# 9                    1.0     0.6931472          5  5.2983655 1.5498215  0.2233227 0.05944982 0.6739965
# 10                   1.0     1.3862944          5  6.4230329 1.8538108  0.1273738 0.02781019 0.6778365
# .cooksd .std.resid
# 1  0.0139540988 -0.5392827
# 2  0.0886414317 -0.9941540
# 3  0.4826245827  1.3111391
# 4  0.0022725303 -0.1050972
# 5  0.0543073747 -0.5043322
# 6  0.0637954916 -0.5362006
# 7  0.0375920888  0.7618349
# 8  0.0057798939  0.4159767
# 9  0.0008399932  0.2302724
# 10 0.0001194412  0.1291827
```

Comment: What about `broom::augment(x=fm1, newdata = Data)`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, `broom::augment(x=fm1, newdata = Data)` gives the same fitted values as `broom::augment(x=fm1)`. Any thoughts.

Comment: You're right. I guess I'm at a loss and I'm not sure what you mean by "predicted values at response scale". I'll have another swing at this. What about `broom::augment(x=fm1, newdata = Data, type.predict = "response")`?

Comment: Thanks @RomanLuštrik for your help. `broom::augment(x=fm1, newdata = Data, type.predict = "response")`. Would appreciate if you change your comment to answer for future reference. Would appreciate if you also explain how to got to know to use `type.predict = "response"`. Earlier I tried  `type = "response"` but did not work and also `args` did not help me. Anyhow thanks for your helpful comment.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For generalized linear model, in order for the math to come out, the model needs to be transformed using a [link function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Link_function). For Gaussian model, this is the identity function, but for logistic regression, we use a logit function (can also be probit, does that ring a bell?). This means that you can get "raw" predicted values or transformed. This is why `?predict.glm` offers a `type` argument, which translates to `type.predict` in `augment`.

```
broom::augment(x=fm1, newdata = Data, type.predict = "response")
```

Comment: Make sense but how you came to know argument `type.predict = "response"`. It is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation of `broom::augment`.

Comment: it's in `?augment.lm` (which should probably have an alias so that `?augment.glm` brings it up as well ...)